# systemctl start custom.service does not return

Tags: shell-script, services, node.js, systemctl

This is my custom service file (elastalert.service)

```
[Unit]
Description=Elastalert
Documentation=https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elastalert.html#configuration
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=Simple
RuntimeDirectory=elastalert
WorkingDirectory=/home/shubham/elastalert
User=shubham
Group=shubham
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/home/shubham/elastalert/startServer.sh
ExecStop=/home/shubham/elastalert/killServer.sh
ExecReload=/home/shubham/elastalert/reloadServer.sh
KillSignal=SIGTERM
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is my startServer.sh script which continuously runs (does not exit).

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/shubham/elastalert
NODE_PATH=. BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 node index.js | ./node_modules/.bin/bunyan -o
```

Executing `sudo systemctl start elastalert.service` neither runs the startServer.sh script nor does it return.

Manual execution of the script works.

The command `sudo journalctl -u elastalert.service` also does not show anything.

Running on Centos 7.

Please Help.

**EDIT**

The script executes after boot automatically but the command `sudo systemctl stop elastalert.service` does not return.

Killing the server (running on port 3030 ) manually works.

Here is the script to kill Server (killServer.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/shubham/elastalert
/bin/kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3030)
rm -f /home/shubham/elastalert/elastalert.pid
```

But then attempting a restart using the command `sudo systemctl start elastalert.service` too does not return.

So the only way to start the server automatically is to restart the VM and to stop the server is to shut the VM down

Comment: Thanks for including all this information in your question! I notice what appears to be an error in your unit file. Please run `systemd-analyze verify /etc/systemd/system/elastalert.service` (or whatever path you put the unit file). Ignore any warnings about other unit files. Look for warnings/errors about your unit file, they should come after any other messages.

Comment: systemd-analyze verify elastalert.service does not show any results. However, it seems that the script does start executing at reboot. However, stopping or reloading using systemctl does not return. Again, if I kill the server manually and attempt to start using systemctl start elastalert.service, this too does not return. So the only way to start the script automatically is restarting the VM

Comment: Ok. On the one hand, on my Fedora Linux, systemd-analyze shows `elastalert.service:7: Failed to parse service type, ignoring: Simple`. If it can't detect that on your system, I think there is a problem, maybe an old bug :-(. I thought this error would explain your problem perfectly, e.g. if systemd was defaulting to `Type=forking`. But that doesn't make sense either, because `man systemd.service` is telling me the default is `Type=simple` anyway.

Comment: `TimeoutStartSec=0` also looks suspicious to me. It definitely should not be needed with `Type=simple`, and it might be one part of what causes `systemctl start` to never return. Note the default start timeout is 90 seconds.

Comment: @sourcejedi I removed `TimeoutStartSec=0` and for safe measure in case its is defaulting to `Type=forking` added PIDFile location under `[Service]` too. Still `sudo systemctl start elastalert.service` does not return or start the server.

Comment: The problem I'm worried about with `Type=forking` is not the pid file.  It is that systemd would expect the program to... "daemonize". systemd would wait for the program to do this. If the program never daemonizes, then systemd would wait forever, and never consider the service as started.

Comment: I do not understand what is happening. Maybe the debug messages would show something. I.e. before you run `systemctl start`, run `systemd-analyze log-level debug`, and then while `systemctl` is waiting, look at `journalctl` again.